# WebStorm + Webpack + Karma - Unable to debug

Tags: typescript, webstorm, webpack-2, karma-webpack

I've searched through what seems like all of the questions in the [webpack] category, but to no avail. The following did not work:

- [Karma + Webpack + sourcemap preprocessor doesn't stop at breakpoints in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988027/karma-webpack-sourcemap-preprocessor-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoints-in-webstorm)
- [webpackJsonp not defined using karma-webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934492/webpackjsonp-not-defined-using-karma-webpack)
- [Karma Webpack sourcemaps not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131809/karma-webpack-sourcemaps-not-working)
- I actually don't see any of the files within the chrome debugger. I think there may be issues as I see this in the WebStorm console: [image: Invalid URLs]

Background: I'm trying to debug the `spec.ts` files from [this seed](https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack). I can not add debug points -- none of the solutions I've come across allow them to be triggered.

Files:

webpack.config.js

```js
// Helper: root() is defined at the bottom
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

// Webpack Plugins
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

/**
 * Env
 * Get npm lifecycle event to identify the environment
 */
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || isTestWatch;
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
  /**
   * Config
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
   * This is the object where all configuration gets set
   */
  var config = {};

  /**
   * Devtool
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
   * Type of sourcemap to use per build type
   */
  if (isProd) {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
  }
  else if (isTest) {
    config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
  }
  else {
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
  }

  if (!isTest) {
    /**
     * Entry
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    config.entry = {
      'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
      'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
      'app': './src/main.ts' // our angular app
    };
  }

  /**
   * Output
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
   */
  config.output = isTest ? {} : {
    path: root('dist'),
    publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: isProd ? '[id].[hash].chunk.js' : '[id].chunk.js'
  };

  /**
   * Resolve
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
   */
  config.resolve = {
    // only discover files that have those extensions
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
  };

  var atlOptions = '';
  if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    // awesome-typescript-loader needs to output inlineSourceMap for code coverage to work with source maps.
    atlOptions = 'inlineSourceMap=true&sourceMap=false';
  }

  /**
   * Loaders
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
   * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html
   * This handles most of the magic responsible for converting modules
   */
  config.module = {
    rules: [
      // Support for .ts files.
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?' + atlOptions, 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader'],
        exclude: [isTest ? /\.(e2e)\.ts$/ : /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
      },

      // copy those assets to output
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'
      },

      // Support for *.json files.
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},

      // Support for CSS as raw text
      // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
      // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: root('src', 'app'),
        loader: isTest ? 'null-loader' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader']})
      },
      // all css required in src/app files will be merged in js files
      {test: /\.css$/, include: root('src', 'app'), loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader'},

      // support for .scss files
      // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
      // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        exclude: root('src', 'app'),
        loader: isTest ? 'null-loader' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']})
      },
      // all css required in src/app files will be merged in js files
      {test: /\.(scss|sass)$/, exclude: root('src', 'style'), loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'},

      // support for .html as raw text
      // todo: change the loader to something that adds a hash to images
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader',  exclude: root('src', 'public')}
    ]
  };

  if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    // instrument only testing sources with Istanbul, covers ts files
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ts$/,
      enforce: 'post',
      include: path.resolve('src'),
      loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
      exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /\.e2e\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
    });
  }

  if (!isTest || !isTestWatch) {
    // tslint support
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ts$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      loader: 'tslint-loader'
    });
  }

  /**
   * Plugins
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
   * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html
   */
  config.plugins = [
    // Define env variables to help with builds
    // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // Environment helpers
      'process.env': {
        ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),

    // Workaround needed for angular 2 angular/angular#11580
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
      root('./src') // location of your src
    ),

    // Tslint configuration for webpack 2
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        /**
         * Apply the tslint loader as pre/postLoader
         * Reference: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
         */
        tslint: {
          emitErrors: false,
          failOnHint: false
        },
        /**
         * Sass
         * Reference: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader
         * Transforms .scss files to .css
         */
        sassLoader: {
          //includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")]
        },
        /**
         * PostCSS
         * Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
         * Add vendor prefixes to your css
         */
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 version']
          })
        ]
      }
    })
  ];

  if (!isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    config.plugins.push(
      // Generate common chunks if necessary
      // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html
      // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
      }),

      // Inject script and link tags into html files
      // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/public/index.html',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
      }),

      // Extract css files
      // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
      // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
      new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'css/[name].[hash].css', disable: !isProd})
    );
  }

  // Add build specific plugins
  if (isProd) {
    config.plugins.push(
      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
      // Only emit files when there are no errors
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

      // // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
      // // Dedupe modules in the output
      // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
      // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true, mangle: { keep_fnames: true }}),

      // Copy assets from the public folder
      // Reference: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: root('src/public')
      }])
    );
  }

  /**
   * Dev server configuration
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
   */
  config.devServer = {
    contentBase: './src/public',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: true,
    stats: 'minimal' // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose
  };

  return config;
}();

// Helper functions
function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```

karma.conf.js:

```js
var path = require('path');

var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';

module.exports = function (config) {
  var _config = {

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'dist/vendor.js',
      { pattern: './karma-shim.js', watched: true }
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      './karma-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    webpackMiddleware: {
      // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
      // i. e.
      stats: 'errors-only'
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true // please don't spam the console when running in karma!
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'mocha'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ["mocha"],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true
  };

  if (!isTestWatch) {
    _config.reporters.push("coverage");

    _config.coverageReporter = {
      dir: 'coverage/',
      reporters: [{
        type: 'json',
        dir: 'coverage',
        subdir: 'json',
        file: 'coverage-final.json'
      }]
    };
  }

  config.set(_config);

};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules doc dist && npm cache clean",
    "clean-install": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "clean-start": "npm run clean-install && npm start",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test webpack --watch --progress --profile",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "lint": "tslint --force \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "e2e-live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "cross-env %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% NODE_ENV=test karma start",
    "posttest": "remap-istanbul -i coverage/json/coverage-final.json -o coverage/html -t html",
    "test-watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch",
    "ci": "npm run e2e && npm run test",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json src/app/app.component.ts",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run server",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server -- --hot",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver-update"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.67",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.39",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.0.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.4.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I missed including it, but I'm using Webstorm 2107.1.3

Comment: Are you unable to add breakpoints in browser devtools during runtime? Do `debugger` statements in the code work?

Comment: @Pavlo breakpoints in the browser work, which is how I've been working for now. Am I fundamentally mistaking where I can actually do debugging? If that's the case, that's okay, just not what I expected.

Comment: @Nava2  strange, I can't get debugging in browser work for https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack project - all I can see in dev tools when opening http://localhost:9876/debug.html is a huge generated karma-shim.js that includes the transpiled specs along with the other stuff. original .ts sources are not available in vm, so I can't create breakpoints. Note: I use `npm test` to run karma, but results are the same when using karma run configuration. What do I miss?

Comment: after changing `atlOptions` to `'sourceMap=true'` I can finally see the .ts sources in Dev Tools; but debugging in WebStorm doesn't work - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27040

Comment: It appears that it has to do with the seed I was using, I setup a brand new project and manually configured it to work. Debugging usually works, and when it fails, debugging in chrome still works.